# TCSH Script - how can I parse invalid argument through the foreach loop?

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I want to parse in my `foreach`, if someone passed an invalid argument, meaning  -(anything here, other than letters 'h' or 'q')

My code:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
foreach i ( $* )
  if($i == "--help" || $i == "-h" )then 
    echo 'Script shows name, surname, login of the invoker. Possible parameters: \n -h/--help - help \n -q/--quit - quit'
    exit 0;
  endif
end

foreach i ( $* )
  if($i == "--quit" || $i == "-q" )then 
    exit 0;
  endif
end
#Here, i thought it will work, but not  
foreach i ( $* )
  if($i == "-*")then
    echo " invalid argument"  
    exit 0;
  endif
end


echo $USER
getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1
exit 0;
```

Comment: The first line should be `#!/bin/tcsh -f`. I suggest using two `echo` commands rather than one with a `\n` in the middle. And I feel obligated to show you [this](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot).

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
if($i =~ [-]*)then
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with not quoting variables when the variable contains a -, so surround all `$i` with double quotes, like this: `"$i"`.

`man tcsh` gives you info about the glob capabilities, search for ''glob-patterns'' and ''Filename substitution''.

The fixed script that works for me is:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
foreach i ( $* )
  if ( "$i" == "--help" || "$i" == "-h" ) then
    echo 'Script shows name, surname, login of the invoker. Possible parameters:'
    echo '  -h/--help - help'
    echo '  -q/--quit - quit'
    exit 1
  endif
  if ( "$i" == "--quit" || "$i" == "-q" ) then
    exit 0
  endif
  if ( "$i" =~ [-]* ) then
    echo " invalid argument: $i"
    exit 0
  endif
end
```